# Math operations on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using PHP and I have the following two tables:

```
REVIEWS

|  id  |  Item   | editor_rating | user_votes  |
------------------------------------------------
|   1  | item_1  |      18.1     |      415    |
|   2  | item_2  |      17.1     |      371    |
|   3  | item_3  |      14.7     |      111    |

|   8  | item_8  |      15.3     |      215    |
|   9  | item_9  |      17.7     |      119    |
|  10  | item_10 |      17.0     |      66     |


FILTERS

|  id  |  Item   |   published   |
----------------------------------
|   1  | item_1  |       1       |
|   2  | item_2  |       1       |
|   3  | item_3  |       1       |

|   8  | item_8  |       1       |
|   9  | item_9  |       1       |
|  10  | item_10 |       1       |
```

The following query works correctly and returns all the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews AS r 
JOIN filters AS f ON (r.id = f.id) 
WHERE f.published = 1
```

So I'm on the right way.
Now I would like to do some math operations on the records. For example **sum** the fields **editor_rating** and **user_votes** and list the rows ordered by DESC. I tried the following but it returns **uncorrect** results (not MySQL error, a sum error):

```
 SELECT *, r.editor_rating+r.user_votes AS total FROM reviews AS r 
 JOIN filters AS f ON (r.id = f.id) 
 WHERE f.published = 1 ORDER BY total DESC
```

The tables above contains the actual dB data. By summing **editor_rating** and **user_votes** I should have a list ordered as follows:

```
18.1 + 415 = 433.1 = Item_1
17.1 + 371 = 388.1 = Item_2
15.3 + 215 = 230.3 = Item_8
```

instead I get the following list:

```
Item_8
Item_9
Item_10
```

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles, and thank us only by contributing back to the community.

Comment: query looks ok. what are the inputs, and expected results.. and what did you get?

Comment: Is the datatype for `editor_rating` **FLOAT** and that of `user_votes` **INT**? Otherwise you will need to cast the values like George suggested. Your query returns the right order as is now.

Comment: @George and inhan, yes datatype are float and int. I tried CAST but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

First check if these values is varchar then you have to cast it first :

```
 SELECT *, cast(r.editor_rating as unsigned )+ cast(r.user_rating as unsigned ) AS total FROM reviews AS r JOIN filters AS f ON (r.id = f.id) WHERE f.published = 1 ORDER BY total DESC
```

It run for me when i cast it first to unsigned integer ..